# Remove outlier from a single cell in R

Tags: r, outliers

I am a newbie in R and I am stuck with a problem removing some outliers. I have a dataframe which is something like this:

```
Item1   Item2   Item3
 4.05    3.9   3.6
 12      3.7   4
 4.01    3.8   4
```

My desired result should be something like the table below, namely a table where the outliers of every column are removed

```
Item1  Item2  Item3 
4.05    3.9    3.6
NA      3.7    4
4.01    3.8    4
```

So far I have written a code which can detect the outliers, but I am stuck with removing them, as the entire column changes instead of the single value.

```
 find_outlier <- function(log_reaction_time) {
media <- mean(log_reaction_time)
devst <- sd(log_reaction_time)
result <-which(log_reaction_time < media - 2 * devst | log_reaction_time > media + 2 * devst)
log_reaction_time2 <- ifelse (log_reaction_time %in% result, NA, log_reaction_time)
}
apply(log_reaction_time, 2, find_outlier)
```

I guess the problem comes from the fact that I apply the function over the columns (2), as I want to find the outliers of the column, but then I want to remove only the relevant values...

Comment: The problem is how you define outlier, if you use quantiles and IQR, your first column does not have outliers.

Comment: Instead of using the quantiles, I am removing every value outside the mean +/- 2 standard deviation. I think that the code I have found detects correctly the outliers, I just want to remove the cell and not the entire column. But thank you!

Comment: And `log_reaction_time` lies outside this dataframe?

Comment: log_reaction_time is the name of the dataframe. So my idea was: I define the function as applying to the df, then I apply it to the different columns.

Comment: I'm confused mean(log_reaction_time) is the is the mean of every entry or just one column?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. log_reaction_time is the name of the dataframe, the columns are Item1, Item2 and so on. What I want is to remove those values outside  mean +/- 2 standard deviation, where this interval is calculated for the distribution of each column. Thank you!

Comment: I gave you solutions for both by column and across entire dataframe.  Your desired outcome seems to be for the entire dataframe which made no sense to me.  But you can do it if you want just have to make the df a matrix first so you can calculate mean and sd for everything.

Comment: While perhaps inconvenient, reaction times that are outside some range, say 3.6~4.05, might be indicative of a behavior, that while not in the range (normals?) evinces something either about the test or the participant or both. Just saying to have a plan to exclude data over and above mere thresholding, if this is behavioral data. My thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use same dataset to show this:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(Item1 = c(4.05, 12, 4.01), Item2 = c(3.9, 3.7, 
3.8), Item3 = c(3.6, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df1
  Item1 Item2 Item3
1  4.05   3.9   3.6
2 12.00   3.7   4.0
3  4.01   3.8   4.0
```

Now the function:

```
#Function
find_outlier <- function(log_reaction_time) {
  media <- mean(log_reaction_time)
  devst <- sd(log_reaction_time)
  result <-which(log_reaction_time < media - 2 * devst | log_reaction_time > media + 2 * devst)
  log_reaction_time[result] <- NA
  return(log_reaction_time)
}

apply(df1, 2, find_outlier)

     Item1 Item2 Item3
[1,]  4.05   3.9   3.6
[2,] 12.00   3.7   4.0
[3,]  4.01   3.8   4.0
```

To highlight, second value for `Item1` is not set to `NA` because `mean(df1$Item1)=6.69` and `sd(df1$Item1)=4.60`. So when the condition checks in the intervals you will have `mean(df1$Item1)-2*sd(df1$Item1)=-2.51` and `mean(df1$Item1)+2*sd(df1$Item1)=15.89` where `12` is not in those limits. You will have to define other criteria to assign it `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure which you want but here's a tidyverse solution for either...

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x < mean(x) - 2 * sd(x) | x > mean(x) + 2 * sd(x) , 
                                NA_real_, 
                                x))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Item1 Item2 Item3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  4.05   3.9   3.6
#> 2 12      3.7   4  
#> 3  4.01   3.8   4

media <- mean(as.matrix(df))
devst <- sd(as.matrix(df))

df %>% 
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x < media - 2 * devst | x > media + 2 * devst , 
                                NA_real_, 
                                x))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Item1 Item2 Item3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  4.05   3.9   3.6
#> 2 NA      3.7   4  
#> 3  4.01   3.8   4
```

Your data

```r
library(readr)
df <- read_table("Item1   Item2   Item3
4.05    3.9   3.6
12      3.7   4
4.01    3.8   4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, if `df` is the first data.frame in your post, the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), find_outlier)) -> new_df
```